# Is there a faster way to duplicate attributes than using Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

In the Data tab of the Properties panel, you can go to the Color Attributes drop-down menu, click on the context menu and duplicate Color Attributes. Is there anything similar for other Attributes? I know that I can use Geometry nodes and just funnel an attribute straight from the input to the output, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to accomplish the same thing.